# [Exception caught by image resource service]. to crash app

Tags: flutter, exception, build, crash

When I build a release app and then install it on the actual device, when there is an error [Exception caught by image resource service], the app crashes and shuts down the app. But the remaining projects do not have this error. Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHhFH.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFwgM.png)

Comment: check your image is available in api or not, because 404 status code means : the server cannot find the requested resource

Comment: I have errorWidget in CachedNetworkImage but until throw Exception so my app crash :(

Comment: your flutter doctor has 2 issues, fix it and then restart and check again

Comment: i fixed it but still getting throw exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please provide the code where did you want to show image, so we can proper guide you.

Comment: I have errorWidget in CachedNetworkImage but until throw Exception

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]

I have use errorWidget but until throw Exception :(

Comment: make sure you have added internet permission in android manifest.